# Android Interfacing with Ethernet Connection

Tags: android

On My Android device i have both Ethernet and Wifi Network connections.
What i wan to implement is I want to check if Wifi and Ethernet both the connections are Active at the same time then I wan to disable the Wifi Network and Keep Ethernet Connection ON.

I am using android `WifiManager` and BroadcastReceiver `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` for Checking Wifi state Connected/Disconnected and also to Enabling/Disabling the Wifi Network.

But I am not able to check the Ethernet Connection State and also I am not able to Enable/Disable the Ethernet Connection.

For Checking the Ethernet connection sate I am reading system file '/sys/class/net/eth0' which is returning me Correct Ethernet State. But for Enabling/Disabling Ethernet I am not able to figure it out how to do it.

I have Ethernet Connection Options in the Settings menu provided by the Android from where we can configure Ethernet connection of the device.

In the `ConnectivityManager` there is an API `getActiveNetworkInfo` which only returns the currently connection network interface, But I want to retrieve the list of all the Connected Interfaces from where we can connect to internet.

Is there any service running on Android that can give me Access to Enable/Disable Ethernet connection and also API to get the Ethernet connection state?

Thanks.

Comment: can u change the ethernet state and IP address? how?

Comment: Have u done enabling/disabling ethernet connection progrmatically? It was  on rooted device or possible with non rooted device as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One Way of archiving it,
Current Ethernet state of Android Device is updated in the file `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` by Android operating system. We need to read this file for getting the state.

File will contain string `UP` if Ethernet is up else string `DOWN` if Ethernet is down.

I tried this way and it is working for me.

But not sure if it will work on all the devices with all the Android versions.

Comment: How you are connecting to Ethernet programmatically ? Any code pls ? @A_user

Comment: Have you confirmed that writing value in this file will enable/disable Ethernet?

Comment: We don't write to this file, we read this file for getting the current state of Ethernet. Writing part is done by the OS.

Comment: Hmm, well, couldn't you just check if Ethernet has an IP address; usually when there is no ip, there is no ethernet connection. Seems simple enough. Works for me.